# Clearing the datagrid combobox using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am having a normal combo box and a datagrid combobox, when I select a particular item in a normal combobox, I want its relative items to be displayed in the datagrid combobox. It works well. But when I change the item in the normal combobox, items in the datagrid combobox gets added to the previous items, but I want it to be reset.

```
     Private Sub cmbGroupId_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbGroupId.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.Open()
    Dim theQuery2 As String = "select [GroupName] from [RuralDevelopmentProject].[dbo].[Groups] WHERE GroupID='" + cmbGroupId.Text + "'"
    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery2, con)
    Dim str As String = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
    txtGroupName.Text = str
    cmd2.Dispose()

    Dim theQuery3 As String = "select [MemberName] from [RuralDevelopmentProject].[dbo].[Member] WHERE GroupID='" + cmbGroupId.Text + "'"
    Dim cmd3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery3, con)
    Dim dr3 As SqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
    While dr3.Read()
        ShortName.Items.Add(dr3(0).ToString)
    End While
    dr3.Close()
    cmd3.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `ShortName.Items.Clear()` right before `While dr3.Read() ...`

Comment: if i add that i get error while selecting the normal combo box for the second  time. System.ArgumentException:DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

Comment: how to reset the values in the datagridcomboboxcell?

Comment: can you please also post the code of your datagrid?

Comment: solved it by adding ShortName.Items.Clear() above connection String.